# OAuth callback URL parameters with Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm Using OAuth2 with Doorkeeper to protect my API.

The problem is that one client had several different flows in which he redirects users to my OAuth flow.

He would like to **dynamically add some parameters** when redirecting the user to my OAuth flow and **get these parameters back** when I'm calling his callback URL. This way he will be able to tell from which flow this callback originated.

Is this possible with OAuth 2? with Doorkeeper? How?

**Edit:**

Thanks Zólyomi István for your hint.
I set the state parameter before calling the auth endpoint and got it back in the callback. However, I found that I get back a state parameter with some apparently random string even if I don't set anything. Any idea what it is? I'd like to be sure I'm not messing up anything...

Comment: It is definitely possible with OAuth2. You can save your state information to parameter 'state' in an OAuth2 request for any flow. Its value will be returned to you with the authorization result, so you get your state back, it should do exactly what you want to achieve. However, I'm not familiar with Doorkeeper, so I cannot help you with the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I set the state parameter before calling the auth endpoint and  got it back. However, I found that I get a state parameter with some apparently random string even if I don't set anything. Any idea what it is?

Comment: My only idea is that it's a bug. ;-)

Comment: You should not get anything in the state parameter if you don't set it, unless your client library is setting up for you. Did you implement the client in this case?

Comment: (you can always post an issue on the repository https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/issues)

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented the client using omniauth oauth2 strategy. maybe something in there sets this parameter. I'll probably need to look into it some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using the state parameter was indeed the solution. Just adding state to the request and then getting it back when the control is returned to my code.
According to the specification:

> The state parameter is used to link requests and callbacks to prevent
>   CSRF attacks where an attacker authorizes access to his own resources
>   and then tricks a users into following a edirect with the attacker's
>   token.

Apparently ominauth oauth 2 assigns random value to this parameter unless it's used in order to detect CSRF attacks.